# Create a video from OpenGL rendered frames

Tags: opengl, osx-mavericks, qt5, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create a video file from an animation I have in OpenGL.
I have been reading on how to do that and to my understanding there are two options:

1. Save each rendered frame in OpenGL to an image file and then create a video file from those
2. Get the frame data using `glReadPixels()` and on the fly write those to a video file

The second approach is what I believe would work best for me, however, I cannot find info on how to achieve the second part (write to a video file).

Can anyone point me out to some web sites where I learn how to do that? What kind of libraries are out there that I can use to encode(?) a video from the frames I am rendering in OpenGL?

**EDIT**

After searching a bit more about this, I believe ffmpeg is the way to go. I found [this blog](http://blog.mmacklin.com/2013/06/11/real-time-video-capture-with-ffmpeg/) that has a code that apparently works on windows.

I have downloaded ffmpeg from the website so that I can execute the command just as in the example. Unfortunately, my application crashes and no video is being created. I checked for the file pointer to be valid but it is not, so I believe the error comes from the execution of the function `popen`.

I am passing the exact same arguments as the command but still no valid file pointer, any idea on what could be happening?

The thing is, I don't want to spend much time coding the video encoding since I have other projects to work on.

Comment: I'm not really experienced in encoding/decoding video files, but I think your best bet would be to look for a library that does that for you, and you just pass the data to it. If its any part the same as audio(which) I imagine it is, it wont be trivial. Unfortunately I don't know of any libraries.

Comment: Problem is, you're not asking for specific help. There are lots of libraries that are able to encode a series of RGB images into a video stream (ffmpeg, gstreamer, I'm pretty sure OSX has something native). Unless you ask for something specific about those libraries this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't use `ffmpeg` directly from my c++ code, a possible solution is as follows. In Qt5 you have the function `paintGL` where you update the frame to be rendered. After it,  get the pixels with `glReadPixels` and then just save the frame as a png image using `QImage`

```
void OpenGLViewer::paintGL()
{
    // Clear screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Update array attached to OpenGL

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, _points);

    update();

    glReadPixels(0, 0, this->width(), this->height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _buffer);

    std::stringstream name;
    name << "Frame" << _frame++ << ".png";
    QString filename(name.str().c_str());
    QImage imagen(_buffer, this->width(), this->height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    imagen.save(filename, "PNG");
}
```

This will leave a bunch of images in your working directory that you can encode in a video using the following command from the console

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i Frame%d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -vf vflip test.avi`

I still have to check why the colors are inverted but for now this works fine since the animation is the important thing and not the colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way after installing libpng:
 uint8_t *pixels = new uint8_t[w*h*3];
 glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *) pixels);

```
for (int j = 0; j * 2 < h; ++j) {
int x = j * w * 3;
int y = (h - 1 - j) * w * 3;
for (int i = w * 3; i > 0; --i) {
    uint8_t tmp = pixels[x];
    pixels[x] = pixels[y];
    pixels[y] = tmp;
    ++x;
    ++y;
    }
}
```

png_structp png = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!png)
        return false;

```
png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
if (!info) {
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);
    return false;
}
std::string s = "IMAGE/"+string(filename);
FILE *fp = fopen(s.c_str(), "wb");
if (!fp) {
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);
    return false;
}

png_init_io(png, fp);
png_set_IHDR(png, info, w, h, 8 , PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
    PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);
png_colorp palette = (png_colorp)png_malloc(png, PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH * sizeof(png_color));
if (!palette) {
    fclose(fp);
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);
    return false;
}
png_set_PLTE(png, info, palette, PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH);
png_write_info(png, info);
png_set_packing(png);

png_bytepp rows = (png_bytepp)png_malloc(png, h * sizeof(png_bytep));
for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    rows[i] = (png_bytep)(pixels + (h - i - 1) * w * 3);

png_write_image(png, rows);
png_write_end(png, info);
png_free(png, palette);
png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);

fclose(fp);
delete[] rows;
```

Comment: ffmpeg -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i Frame%d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -vf vflip test.avi